# Any way to share js libraries between two apps via browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am using Browserify to manage my project, now the problem is my website has two pages, every page need a start point, page1.js and page2.js, all of them depends on JQuery library, I us Browserify to bundle the output as bundle1.js and bundle2.js.

Now the problem is bundle1.js and bundle2.js all have a jquery, any way to make client load jquery once, then share jquery instance between bundle1.js and bundle2.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are loading Jquery through a script tag defined in the html page. The browser should cache that js file. As a result you would not have to do it again.

And if your talking about a different file that uses jquery. You can store that file in local storage. And when you go to your second page, just check in bundle2 if a script is stored in local storage if it is. Retreive it and execute it.

http://addyosmani.github.io/basket.js/    * This might be worth checking out.